Forwarding issue: no ping from IPSec subnet via Wireguard subnet

Problem: i1NN-clients are not able to reach hosts in remote networks like (yc1-subnet).

wireguard-peer {y} connects to {p} and receives 172.27.0.21/24 IP address in the (wireguard-subnet)

{y} is able to ping {p} and vice versa by 172.27.0.1 and 172.27.0.21

ikev2-peer [i1NN] connects to {p} and receives 10.127.3.1NN/24 IP address in the (ipsec-subnet)

[i1NN] is able to ping {p}

routes on {p}


10.128.0.0/24 via 172.27.0.21
10.128.255.0/24 via 172.27.0.21

... (others are similar)

forwards on {p}

src-address=10.127.3.0/24 dst-address=10.128.0.0/24
src-address=10.128.0.0/24 dst-address=10.127.3.0/24
src-address=10.127.3.0/24 dst-address=10.128.255.0/24
src-address=10.128.255.0/24 dst-address=10.127.3.0/24

... (others are similar)

forwards on {y}

src-address=172.27.0.0/24 dst-address=10.128.0.0/24
src-address=10.128.0.0/24 dst-address=172.27.0.0/24
src-address=172.27.0.0/24 dst-address=10.128.255.0/24
src-address=10.128.255.0/24 dst-address=172.27.0.0/24


routes on {y}

10.127.3.0/24 via 172.27.0.1
...

{p}, {y}, {o}, {a} are RouterOS hosts
[i1NN] - macOS and Windows desktops
I guess that I do not understand correctly basics but believe that I need just forwards without address translations.
What am I missing?
Thank you!
